# What happens when we dereference a FILE pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose I have a file pointer

```
FILE* infile = fopen("<somefilepath", "r");
```

Now when I dereference the file pointer in gdb then I get

print *infile

│$2 = {_flags = -72539000, _IO_read_ptr = 0x0, _IO_read_end = 0x0,
│  _IO_read_base = 0x0, _IO_write_base = 0x0, _IO_write_ptr = 0x0,
│  _IO_write_end = 0x0, _IO_buf_base = 0x0, _IO_buf_end = 0x0,
│  _IO_save_base = 0x0, _IO_backup_base = 0x0, _IO_save_end = 0x0, _markers = 0x0,
                                                                                        │  _chain = 0x7ffff7dd41c0 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>, _fileno = 3, _flags2 = 0,
                                                                                        │  _old_offset = 0, _cur_column = 0, _vtable_offset = 0 '\000', _shortbuf = "",
                                                                                        │  _lock = 0x6020f0, _offset = -1, __pad1 = 0x0, __pad2 = 0x602100, __pad3 = 0x0,
                                                                                        │  __pad4 = 0x0, __pad5 = 0, _mode = 0, _unused2 = '\000' }

Can someone help me understand what this means ?

Comment: That's what a `FILE` contains in your library implementation. If you're wondering what all those members mean, the answer to that would be too long, and both too broad and too specific for this site..

Comment: The same it means for any other struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C11 7.21.1/2 describes `FILE` as

> …an object type capable of recording all the information needed to
>   control a stream, including its file position indicator,a pointer to
>   its associated buffer (if any), an error indicator that records
>   whether a read/write error has occurred, and an end-of-file indicator
>   that records whether the end of the file has been reached;

But doesn't mention specific members.  Here is glibc's implementation that you observed (I deleted unused preprocessor branches for clarity):

```
struct _IO_FILE {
  int _flags;       /* High-order word is _IO_MAGIC; rest is flags. */
#define _IO_file_flags _flags

  /* The following pointers correspond to the C++ streambuf protocol. */
  /* Note:  Tk uses the _IO_read_ptr and _IO_read_end fields directly. */
  char* _IO_read_ptr;   /* Current read pointer */
  char* _IO_read_end;   /* End of get area. */
  char* _IO_read_base;  /* Start of putback+get area. */
  char* _IO_write_base; /* Start of put area. */
  char* _IO_write_ptr;  /* Current put pointer. */
  char* _IO_write_end;  /* End of put area. */
  char* _IO_buf_base;   /* Start of reserve area. */
  char* _IO_buf_end;    /* End of reserve area. */
  /* The following fields are used to support backing up and undo. */
  char *_IO_save_base; /* Pointer to start of non-current get area. */
  char *_IO_backup_base;  /* Pointer to first valid character of backup area */
  char *_IO_save_end; /* Pointer to end of non-current get area. */

  struct _IO_marker *_markers;

  struct _IO_FILE *_chain;

  int _fileno;
  int _flags2;
  _IO_off_t _old_offset; /* This used to be _offset but it's too small.  */

#define __HAVE_COLUMN /* temporary */
  /* 1+column number of pbase(); 0 is unknown. */
  unsigned short _cur_column;
  signed char _vtable_offset;
  char _shortbuf[1];

  /*  char* _save_gptr;  char* _save_egptr; */

  _IO_lock_t *_lock;

  _IO_off64_t _offset;
  void *__pad1;
  void *__pad2;
  void *__pad3;
  void *__pad4;
  size_t __pad5;
  int _mode;
  /* Make sure we don't get into trouble again.  */
  char _unused2[15 * sizeof (int) - 4 * sizeof (void *) - sizeof (size_t)];
};
```

Answer (score 6):

`FILE *` should be considered an opaque value... Dereferencing it will be platform/library-dependent (and thus not portable).

Answer (score -1):

`FILE` is described in the C standard, section 7.21.1:

> 2 The types declared are **size_t** (described in 7.19);
>
> **FILE**
>
> which is an object type capable of recording all the information
>   needed to control a stream, including its file position indicator, a
>   pointer to its associated buffer (if any), an *error indicator* that
>   records whether a read/write error has occurred, and an *end-of-file*
>   indicator that records whether the end of the file has been reached;
>   ...

In your particular instance, it seems you are using glibc. It's implementation of `FILE` can found in [`libio.h`](https://github.com/h4ck3rm1k3/glibc/blob/54399c08c32eed07b3db579210261ea9487baff3/libio/libio.h#L246):

```
struct _IO_FILE {
  int _flags;       /* High-order word is _IO_MAGIC; rest is flags. */
#define _IO_file_flags _flags

  /* The following pointers correspond to the C++ streambuf protocol. */
  /* Note:  Tk uses the _IO_read_ptr and _IO_read_end fields directly. */
  char* _IO_read_ptr;   /* Current read pointer */
  char* _IO_read_end;   /* End of get area. */
  char* _IO_read_base;  /* Start of putback+get area. */
  char* _IO_write_base; /* Start of put area. */
  char* _IO_write_ptr;  /* Current put pointer. */
  char* _IO_write_end;  /* End of put area. */
  char* _IO_buf_base;   /* Start of reserve area. */
  char* _IO_buf_end;    /* End of reserve area. */
  /* The following fields are used to support backing up and undo. */
  char *_IO_save_base; /* Pointer to start of non-current get area. */
  char *_IO_backup_base;  /* Pointer to first valid character of backup area */
  char *_IO_save_end; /* Pointer to end of non-current get area. */

  struct _IO_marker *_markers;

  struct _IO_FILE *_chain;

  int _fileno;
#if 0
  int _blksize;
#else
  int _flags2;
#endif
  _IO_off_t _old_offset; /* This used to be _offset but it's too small.  */

#define __HAVE_COLUMN /* temporary */
  /* 1+column number of pbase(); 0 is unknown. */
  unsigned short _cur_column;
  signed char _vtable_offset;
  char _shortbuf[1];

  /*  char* _save_gptr;  char* _save_egptr; */

  _IO_lock_t *_lock;
#ifdef _IO_USE_OLD_IO_FILE
};
```

Keep in mind the full implementation spans many files, functions, data structures, etc.